# Adding a derived interface to generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I've got these interfaces:

[image]

And this code:

```
IList<IFinder<IDomainObject>> finders = new List<IFinder<IDomainObject>>();
IFinder<IOrder> orderFinder = this.mocks.StrictMock<IFinder<IOrder>>();
finders.Add(orderFinder);
```

I get this error on the third line:

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'Mes.FrameworkTest.Repository.Finders.IFinder`<Mes.FrameworkTest.DomainModel.IOrder`>' to 'Mes.FrameworkTest.Repository.Finders.IFinder`<Mes.FrameworkTest.DomainModel.IDomainObject`>'

Why do I get this error when IOrder is derived from IDomainObject?

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires .Net 4's support for covariance, which would be expressed thus:

```
interface IFinder<out T> ...
```

If you don't have .Net 4 (VS 2010), you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes I've done this in .NET 3.5 and VS 2008.
But I just tried updating it to VS 2010 and the projects to .NET 4 and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: ... but that might be because IList or my own IFinder doesn't support covariance?

Comment: @Paw: You have to add the `out` specifier to your interface's generic type parameter.

Comment: @Adam: Thank you :) It works now.
Now I just need to make my team upgrade to VS 2010 ASAP ;) Shouldn't be that big a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Covariance and Contravariance in generics are new .Net 4.0 features i think.
Good read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx